# heroku django - process based on static file path (like nginx config in normal server) or atleast middleware

Tags: python, django, heroku

I want my django based heroku app to redirect /static/images/abc.png__someconstantstring to some other url.

Usually I handle it using nginx.

But, in heroku, I dont think I can configure static files routing, so I tried using middleware but request.path printing "/favicon.ico" (Tested locally, not on heroku).

Whats the solution? I think I missed something regarding middleware, so what can be the reason?

Anyway, I dont think heroku allows static files requests via django server, may be it will be handled using something else. So, definitely I think I cant do using middleware, urls etc. There may be some solution related to static file routing in heroku. Can you tell me that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can force your django app server serve static content for you by defining custom view and adding it into URLs like this:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', view.MyStaticFilesView.as_view()),
)
```

So now you can get `path` variable and create your own logic. Just ensure that you return images, texts or any other content with propper content-type. And also you can track `__someconstantstring` and redirect anywhere you want.

This method will cause additional load to your app server.